# How to inject Javascript in WebBrowser control?

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I've tried this:

```
string newScript = textBox1.Text;
HtmlElement head = browserCtrl.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
HtmlElement scriptEl = browserCtrl.Document.CreateElement("script");
lblStatus.Text = scriptEl.GetType().ToString();
scriptEl.SetAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
head.AppendChild(scriptEl);
scriptEl.InnerHtml = "function sayHello() { alert('hello') }";
```

scriptEl.InnerHtml and scriptEl.InnerText both give errors:

```
System.NotSupportedException: Property is not supported on this type of HtmlElement.
   at System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement.set_InnerHtml(String value)
   at SForceApp.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\jsight\installs\SForceApp\SForceApp\Form1.cs:line 31
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Is there an easy way to inject a script into the dom?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

For some reason Richard's solution didn't work on my end (insertAdjacentText failed with an exception). This however seems to work:

```
HtmlElement head = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
HtmlElement scriptEl = webBrowser1.Document.CreateElement("script");
IHTMLScriptElement element = (IHTMLScriptElement)scriptEl.DomElement;
element.text = "function sayHello() { alert('hello') }";
head.AppendChild(scriptEl);
webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("sayHello");
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5216255/157247) explains how to get the `IHTMLScriptElement` interface into your project.

Comment: Cool, I think the IHTMLScriptElement usage makes the code intent more obvious in any case.  I do wonder why you got an exception, but c'est la vie with COM interop sometimes.

Comment: What about adding a reference to a local js file? Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029602/how-do-i-add-a-local-script-file-to-the-html-of-a-webbrowser-control

Comment: Please help me with this. How did you do this. I want to inject JS into my page in real time through my C++ app. How should i go about it.

Comment: is this applicable to inject jquery file also?

Answer (score 53):

```
HtmlDocument doc = browser.Document;
HtmlElement head = doc.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
HtmlElement s = doc.CreateElement("script");
s.SetAttribute("text","function sayHello() { alert('hello'); }");
head.AppendChild(s);
browser.Document.InvokeScript("sayHello");
```

(tested in .NET 4 / Windows Forms App)

Edit: Fixed case issue in function set.

Comment: I appreciated this solution because it doesn't rely on the (albeit useful!) IHTMLSCriptElement assembly.

Comment: @jsight This should be the accepted answer.  It is the same as the current answer, but simpler and without the `IHTMLSCriptElement` dependency.

Answer (score 33):

Here is the easiest way that I found after working on this:

```
string javascript = "alert('Hello');";
// or any combination of your JavaScript commands
// (including function calls, variables... etc)

// WebBrowser webBrowser1 is what you are using for your web browser
webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("eval", new object[] { javascript });
```

What global JavaScript function `eval(str)` does is parses and executes whatever is written in str.
Check [w3schools ref here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp).

Answer (score 22):

Also, in .NET 4 this is even easier if you use the dynamic keyword:

```
dynamic document = this.browser.Document;
dynamic head = document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
dynamic scriptEl = document.CreateElement("script");
scriptEl.text = ...;
head.AppendChild(scriptEl);
```

Comment: Why would anyone need dynamic for that? If you're trying to save some typing, we do have type inference since C# 3.0 so var would be acceptable. There's no need to start invoking the DLR.

Comment: This is basically exactly the point of the dynamic keyword: COM interop. You don't actually have Type Inference here, you have documentation. Because an IHTMLElement2 is not assignable from IHtmlElement for example, and at runtime you just have a COM proxy object. You just have to know which interfaces to cast into what. The dynamic keyword helps you cut down on a lot of that cruft. You know the method exists why cast it into some interface? It doesn't exactly 'invoke the DLR' it just generates code that knows how to invoke method on COM objects (in this case).

Comment: @justin.m.chase you saved my life.

Answer (score 17):

If all you really want is to run javascript, this would be easiest (VB .Net):

```
MyWebBrowser.Navigate("javascript:function foo(){alert('hello');}foo();")
```

I guess that this wouldn't "inject" it but it'll run your function, if that's what you're after.  (Just in case you've over-complicated the problem.)  And if you can figure out how to inject in javascript, put that into the body of the function "foo" and let the javascript do the injection for you.

Answer (score 10):

The managed wrapper for the HTML document doesn't completely implement the functionality you need, so you need to dip into the MSHTML API to accomplish what you want:

1) Add a reference to MSHTML, which will probalby be called "Microsoft HTML Object Library" under *COM* references.

2) Add 'using mshtml;' to your namespaces.

3) Get a reference to your script element's IHTMLElement:

```
IHTMLElement iScriptEl = (IHTMLElement)scriptEl.DomElement;
```

4) Call the insertAdjacentText method, with the first parameter value of "afterBegin".  All the possible values are listed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa170712(office.11).aspx):

```
iScriptEl.insertAdjacentText("afterBegin", "function sayHello() { alert('hello') }");
```

5) Now you'll be able to see the code in the scriptEl.InnerText property.

Hth,
Richard

Comment: Nice... this together with the tips provided by korchev works perfectly.  I wish I could set two accepted solutions on this one. :)

Answer (score 9):

I believe the most simple method to inject Javascript in a WebBrowser Control HTML Document from c# is to invoke the  "execScript" method with the code to be injected as argument.

In this example the javascript code is injected and executed at global scope:

```
var jsCode="alert('hello world from injected code');";
WebBrowser.Document.InvokeScript("execScript", new Object[] { jsCode, "JavaScript" });
```

If you want to delay execution, inject functions and call them after:

```
var jsCode="function greet(msg){alert(msg);};";
WebBrowser.Document.InvokeScript("execScript", new Object[] { jsCode, "JavaScript" });
...............
WebBrowser.Document.InvokeScript("greet",new object[] {"hello world"});
```

This is valid for Windows Forms and WPF WebBrowser controls.

This solution is not cross browser because "execScript" is defined only in IE and Chrome. But the question is about Microsoft WebBrowser controls and IE is the only one supported.

For a valid cross browser method to inject javascript code, create a Function object with the new Keyword. This example creates an anonymous function with injected code and executes it (javascript implements closures and the function has access to global space without local variable pollution).

```
var jsCode="alert('hello world');";
(new Function(code))();
```

Of course, you can delay execution:

```
var jsCode="alert('hello world');";
var inserted=new Function(code);
.................
inserted();
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 8):

As a follow-up to the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/154496/107625), this is a minimal definition of the [`IHTMLScriptElement` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768904%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which does not require to include additional type libraries:

```
[ComImport, ComVisible(true), Guid(@"3050f28b-98b5-11cf-bb82-00aa00bdce0b")]
[InterfaceTypeAttribute(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
[TypeLibType(TypeLibTypeFlags.FDispatchable)]
public interface IHTMLScriptElement
{
    [DispId(1006)]
    string text { set; [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] get; }
}
```

So a full code inside a WebBrowser control derived class would look like:

```
protected override void OnDocumentCompleted(
    WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnDocumentCompleted(e);

    // Disable text selection.
    var doc = Document;
    if (doc != null)
    {
        var heads = doc.GetElementsByTagName(@"head");
        if (heads.Count > 0)
        {
            var scriptEl = doc.CreateElement(@"script");
            if (scriptEl != null)
            {
                var element = (IHTMLScriptElement)scriptEl.DomElement;
                element.text =
                    @"function disableSelection()
                    { 
                        document.body.onselectstart=function(){ return false; }; 
                        document.body.ondragstart=function() { return false; };
                    }";
                heads[0].AppendChild(scriptEl);
                doc.InvokeScript(@"disableSelection");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

this is a solution using mshtml

```
IHTMLDocument2 doc = new HTMLDocumentClass();
doc.write(new object[] { File.ReadAllText(filePath) });
doc.close();

IHTMLElement head = (IHTMLElement)((IHTMLElementCollection)doc.all.tags("head")).item(null, 0);
IHTMLScriptElement scriptObject = (IHTMLScriptElement)doc.createElement("script");
scriptObject.type = @"text/javascript";
scriptObject.text = @"function btn1_OnClick(str){
    alert('you clicked' + str);
}";
((HTMLHeadElementClass)head).appendChild((IHTMLDOMNode)scriptObject);
```

Comment: As this is a community resource, his answer is still useful to others (like myself). +1 for mshtml equivalent, saved me a question.

Comment: For anyone that finds this, remove 'class' from the last line, should read `((HTMLHeadElement)head).appendChild((IHTMLDOMNode)scriptObject);` you will get errors otherwise.

Comment: Is there anyway this answer can get promoted by admins? The ones above this are all wrong in reality. This one was a late comer but really is the most correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a VB.Net example if you are trying to retrieve the value of a variable from within a page loaded in a WebBrowser control.

Step 1) Add a COM reference in your project to Microsoft HTML Object Library

Step 2) Next, add this VB.Net code to your Form1 to import the mshtml library:
        Imports mshtml

Step 3) Add this VB.Net code above your "Public Class Form1" line:
        <System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisibleAttribute(True)>

Step 4) Add a WebBrowser control to your project

Step 5) Add this VB.Net code to your Form1_Load function:
        WebBrowser1.ObjectForScripting = Me

Step 6) Add this VB.Net sub which will inject a function "CallbackGetVar" into the web page's Javascript:

```vb
Public Sub InjectCallbackGetVar(ByRef wb As WebBrowser)
    Dim head As HtmlElement
    Dim script As HtmlElement
    Dim domElement As IHTMLScriptElement

    head = wb.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")(0)
    script = wb.Document.CreateElement("script")
    domElement = script.DomElement
    domElement.type = "text/javascript"
    domElement.text = "function CallbackGetVar(myVar) { window.external.Callback_GetVar(eval(myVar)); }"
    head.AppendChild(script)
End Sub
```

Step 7) Add the following VB.Net sub which the Javascript will then look for when invoked:

```vb
Public Sub Callback_GetVar(ByVal vVar As String)
    Debug.Print(vVar)
End Sub
```

Step 8) Finally, to invoke the Javascript callback, add this VB.Net code when a button is pressed, or wherever you like:

```vb
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    WebBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("CallbackGetVar", New Object() {"NameOfVarToRetrieve"})
End Sub
```

Step 9) If it surprises you that this works, you may want to read up on the Javascript "eval" function, used in Step 6, which is what makes this possible.  It will take a string and determine whether a variable exists with that name and, if so, returns the value of that variable.

Answer (score 2):

I used this :D

```
HtmlElement script = this.WebNavegador.Document.CreateElement("SCRIPT");
script.SetAttribute("TEXT", "function GetNameFromBrowser() {" + 
"return 'My name is David';" + 
"}");

this.WebNavegador.Document.Body.AppendChild(script);
```

Then you can execute and get the result with:

```
string myNameIs = (string)this.WebNavegador.Document.InvokeScript("GetNameFromBrowser");
```

I hope to be helpful

Answer (score 1):

You can always use a "DocumentStream" or "DocumentText" property.
For working with HTML documents I recommend a [HTML Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack).

Comment: Nice tip... I'm sure that lib will come in handy at some point.

Answer (score 1):

i use this:

```
webBrowser.Document.InvokeScript("execScript", new object[] { "alert(123)", "JavaScript" })
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is use Page.RegisterStartupScript(key, script) 
:

See here for more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478975.aspx

What you basically do is build your javascript string, pass it to that method and give it a unique id( in case you try to register it twice on a page.)

EDIT: This is what you call trigger happy. Feel free to down it. :)

Comment: ASP.Net doesn't have much to do with scripting the WebBrowser control in a winforms app.

Comment: I probably would have under-read the same way and given the same incorrect answer

Answer (score 0):

If you need to inject a whole file then you can use this:

```vb
With Browser.Document
   Dim Head As HtmlElement = .GetElementsByTagName("head")(0)
   Dim Script As HtmlElement = .CreateElement("script")
   Dim Streamer As New StreamReader(<Here goes path to file as String>)
   Using Streamer
       Script.SetAttribute("text", Streamer.ReadToEnd())
   End Using
   Head.AppendChild(Script)
   .InvokeScript(<Here goes a method name as String and without parentheses>)
End With
```

Remember to import `System.IO` in order to use the `StreamReader`. I hope this helps.

Comment: I know this was answered 3 days short of a year ago, but would you be able to use this to put a file into an `input type="file"` section?

Answer (score 0):

bibki.js

```
webBrowser1.DocumentText =
     "<html><head><script>" +
     "function test(message) { alert(message); }" +
     "</script></head><body><button " +
     "onclick=\"window.external.Test('called from script code')\">" +
     "call client code from script code</button>" +
      "</body></html>";
```