# WebBrowser Control from MFC — How to Inject Javascript?

Tags: javascript, c++, mfc, browser

This is like the question
[How to inject Javascript in WebBrowser control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153748/webbrowser-control-from-net-how-to-inject-javascript)

But i don't know how to transform this code into good old MFC C++ code.
For example what is the InvokeScript method, i can't find it anywhere.

Isn't .NET webbrowser the same as IWebBrowser2 ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can find a CodeGuru article describing how to accomplish this [here](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/i-n/ieprogram/article.php/c4399).