# web site scraping data

Tags: c#, javascript, dom, webbrowser-control

I am working on web site scraping  project where I am  using webbrowser control in C#.net
I almost done these by going from page to page and collecting data.This project has to run automatically.
One page has JavaScript function and there is  alert message notification is popping up. How I can pass this alert?Is there any way to comment it out or call click method?
Please help with this.

Thank you in advance

Comment: not sure about c# but if you will use something like curl then you will receive just code of the website which will not execute... :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stop alert javascript popup in webbrowser c# control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848632/stop-alert-javascript-popup-in-webbrowser-c-sharp-control)

Comment: Thank you for response. I am still working on this issue.I found it very useful but still it is not complete.One page has submit button.When I want to read javascript function after submission but before navigation to the  next page.Because function has executed before page appears.I can not catch correct Documenttext method.

Comment: I apologize for my English. I could not explain correctly.There are 2 pages.First page has submit button.Next page has alert message.When I click submit alert is executing before url is showing. How I cancatch correct document to work with it.What event I have to use to catch correct document?