# How do I add a local script file to the HTML of a WebBrowser control?

Tags: c#, javascript, html, webbrowser-control

This seems really dumb. I've tried a bunch of different ways and it's just not working. I have a WinForms app with a WebBrowser control. If I try with a raw html file on my desktop using the same src string, the src I put together works fine. But plugging the same stuff into the WebBrowser control won't work.

Here's my code:

```
HtmlElementCollection head = this.wbPreview.Document.GetElementsByTagName( "head" );
if (head != null)
{
    HtmlElement elm = this.webBrowserControl.Document.CreateElement("script");
    string mySource = Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\MyScriptFile.js";
    elm.SetAttribute("src", mySource);
    elm.SetAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
    ((HtmlElement)head[0]).AppendChild(elm);
}
```

The WebBrowser doesn't get the script. However, if I change "mySource" to an external resource (via http://), it works fine!

Help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

i came up on your post, while playing around with things following worked for me:

```
HtmlElementCollection head = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head");
if (head != null)
{
    HtmlElement elm = webBrowser1.Document.CreateElement("script");
    elm.SetAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
    elm.InnerText = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\helperscripts.js");
    ((HtmlElement)head[0]).AppendChild(elm);
}
```

, so all methods of helperscript.js can be invoked using

```
webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("methodname");
```

, here as a reference for the script invoke: [How to inject Javascript in WebBrowser control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153748/how-to-inject-javascript-in-webbrowser-control)

greetings

Comment: getting this error : {"Property is not supported on this type of HtmlElement."}

Comment: It works, but when trying to set a big script to `elm.InnerText`, the process just stops responding for quite a while.

Comment: Depending on your Windows Feature Emulation Version (older ie) `elm.InnerText` may fail. Instead we can use `elm.SetAttribute("TEXT", ... )`

Answer (score 4):

Try adding `file://` to the URL.

Comment: I actually did that and have attempted all other known nomenclatures I was able to find. I've used Absolutes, Relatives, using URI's instead, etc. No go.

Answer (score 1):

[There is a long story](http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2011/06/22/silverlight-html-and-the-webbrowser-control-for-offline-apps.aspx) about workarounds of that "security fix" from MS. New behavior was implemented starting from IE7. Take a look into "base" tag and [IE Feature controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537184%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

I did the following:

```
                    //TODO: if not mono
                var executableFilename = Path.GetFileName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
                var keys = new[] { executableFilename, [vsname]+".vshost.exe" }; //check!

                Action<string, object, string> SetRegistryKeyOrFail =
                    (key, val, regStr) =>
                        {
                            var reg =
                                Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(regStr);
                            if (reg == null) throw new Exception("Failed registry: " + regStr);
                            reg.SetValue(key, val);
                        };

                foreach (var key in keys)
                {
                    SetRegistryKeyOrFail(key, 1, @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BLOCK_LMZ_IMG");
                    SetRegistryKeyOrFail(key, 0, @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BLOCK_LMZ_SCRIPT");
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because of security reasons. You need a webserver to do that, else you can access any file on a system which would be a big security hole.

In developement mode, you can set e.g on chrome:

```
chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files
```

And you will be able to run your code.