# How can I run Prettify in a WPF WebBrowser to apply syntax highlighting?

Tags: c#, wpf, markdown, prettify, markdowndeep

I'm creating a WPF application that allows the user to enter text in a TextBox. This text may contain Markdown syntax, which is evaluated by a [MarkdownDeep](http://www.toptensoftware.com/markdowndeep/) object to convert the text to HTML. I take this output and feed it to a WebBrowser control via a call to `NavigateToString`. (In other words, the WebBrowser control never actually accesses the internet - it's merely a medium to get the rendered output to display.) Generally speaking, this approach works fantastically and I'm very happy with the results.

Now I'm trying to add a new feature where the user can enter actual code and the HTML output will have syntax highlighting for code blocks (similar to how StackOverflow does it). MarkdownDeep has a really nifty hooks that allows programmers to inject their own syntax highlighting. I wanted to use [this example](http://www.toptensoftware.com/blog/posts/83-MarkdownDeep-Syntax-Highlighting) from their website. However, I'm having trouble actually getting the Prettify script to run. I've added the [Prettify NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Prettify/) which added a bunch of scripts to my solution. I don't know how to run them in a WPF application though, and all the examples I've found online were for ASP.NET.

I tried to use WebBrowser's `InvokeScript` method to run the script manually, but I only get COMExceptions (which signify that the script "doesn't exist", even though I can see it in the folder structure).

```
// In XAML file
<WebBrowser x:Name="HtmlOutput"
            local:WebBrowserBehavior.Html="{Binding RenderedText}"
            LoadCompleted="OnLoadCompleted"/>

// In .cs code-behind
private void OnLoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    HtmlOutput.InvokeScript("./Scripts/Prettify/run_prettify.js");
}
```

---

I guess my question can be summarized as this: Given a string of HTML, how can I apply the Prettify JavaScript script?

[If it helps, I have included the full source of an example project as a MVCE [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B54_HhpBuYIeNEpVOEFGRlZRNzA/view?usp=sharing)]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9815114/1271037

Answer (score 0):

Pass the script as absolute path using e.g.

```
 System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```

and do not forget to copy your file into output directory. Visual studio can do this automatically for you (mark file as "content" and choose "copy" in properties tab)