# Get Embed Parameters in a HTML File C# MSHTML

Tags: c#, html

After displaying a webpage using webbroswer control, i also need to read parameters of all the flash objects in the page even the objects embedded by scripts. I could not correctly get all the attributes parsing a HTMLElementCollection is there any other way ?

Comment: The Document property and it's children should reflect runtime modifications  by javascript, so there shouldn't be an issue there so long as you give the javascript time to execute (You could use the DocumentCompleted in combination with a timer to check for modifications).

So what is the problem you're having? Are you unable to get the attributes of the embed tag?

Comment: Also, could you provide some source code and a test case in the form of a URL you're trying to process and the list of embedded flash objects & attributes you'd expect to see returned?

Answer (score 0):

What if you render the webcontrol and then [inject a javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153748/webbrowser-control-from-net-how-to-inject-javascript) that gets all the properties?