# How do submit a form without clicking submit button BUT with code in (C# web browser control)

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser-control

Hi is there a way to submit a form WITHOUT clicking the submit button?

[image]

Keep in mind this is inside the webBrowser1 control in C# . So if i click a button in my C# application it should automatically submit the form.

Comment: You could inject loaded site with javascript (e.g., `document.getElementById('formId').submit();`)

Comment: @PLB can you show me an example pls

Answer (score 0):

You can inject Javascript code that submits the form to the page:

```
// Do this on form load.
HtmlElement head = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
HtmlElement scriptEl = webBrowser1.Document.CreateElement("script");
IHTMLScriptElement element = (IHTMLScriptElement)scriptEl.DomElement;
element.text = "function submitForm() { document.getElementById('formId').submit(); }";
head.AppendChild(scriptEl);
```

Then invoke it on button click:

```
// In button click handler
webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("submitForm");
```

Comment: @ Adi Lester : what is IHTMLScriptElement ?

Comment: It's an interface representing an HTML script. If you're having problems finding it, try [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5216255/389966)

Comment: private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HtmlElement head = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
            HtmlElement scriptEl = webBrowser1.Document.CreateElement("script");
            IHTMLScriptElement element = (IHTMLScriptElement)scriptEl.DomElement;
            element.text = "function submitForm() { document.getElementByName('sendmessage').submit(); }";
            head.AppendChild(scriptEl);
        }

webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("submitForm");

Comment: Keep in mind you do need to change "formId" in the script to the actual id of the form. You can find out what it is by looking at the page's source.

Comment: <form action="sendmessage.aspx" method="post" name="sendmessage">

Comment: Try replacing `document.getElementByName('sendmessage').submit();` with `document.getElementsByName('sendmessage')[0].value.submit();`

Answer (score 0):

Another Way:

```
Webbrowser1.navigate("javascript:document.getElementById('FormId').submit();")
```

There are many ways to do it, if this code not working I'll bring you more examples.