# Perform a click on a Webbrowser control

Tags: vb.net, browser

Does anybody know a good way to perform a click on a control inside of a webbrowser?  Preferably from ID?

Thanks, ALL suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the HtmlElement.InvokeMember("click") method.  Here's a sample form that uses the Google "I feel lucky" button:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        webBrowser1.Url = new Uri("http://google.com");
        webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted;
    }

    void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e) {
        if (webBrowser1.Url.Host.EndsWith("google.com")) {
            HtmlDocument doc = webBrowser1.Document;
            HtmlElement ask = doc.All["q"];
            HtmlElement lucky = doc.All["btnI"];
            ask.InnerText = "stackoverflow";
            lucky.InvokeMember("click");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works but I needed to add this `&& e.Url.ToString()!="about:blank"` to DocumentCompleted if statement

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly call `click` on something in the control. However, you can register some JavaScript into the control and perform the click that way.

See [How to inject Javascript in WebBrowser control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153748/how-to-inject-javascript-in-webbrowser-control) for details.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really for an ID but you can do the same thing with it by using the value button.

```
Dim allelements As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.All

For Each webpageelement As HtmlElement In allelements

If webpageelement.GetAttribute("value") = "Log In" Then

webpageelement.InvokeMember("click")

End If

Next
```