# Embed Google Maps in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, google-maps

I'm developing an App for a Taxi company for my final year project. I'm using Google latitude to track the location of the driver.

I can successfully retrieve both latitude and longitude of the driver (i.e the gps enabled phone) inside C#.

Now I want to show the exact location in a form probably with a pin or mark pointed at the retrieved lat, lon crossing point.

Please help. thanks in advance.

Comment: Tried anything?  Google has copious amounts of documentation and samples........

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is the [landing page](https://developers.google.com/maps/) for the Google maps API. The one you will likely need is [Static Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/) (note you can only get 25 000 uniuqe images per client per day, you will not likely hit this but it is something to be aware of). If you want a interactive map you will need to use a WebBrowser control and use the [javascript api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/)

---

Comment: I acheived wot I wanted using this method. I used static map API. Thanks a lot again :)

Answer (score 7):

Another option is to use a premade control like [this one](http://greatmaps.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Very nice, never seen this before. I like it.

Comment: Wow, very nice, I'd recommend that one, too!

Comment: It appears there is a [tussle going on between them and Google](http://greatmaps.codeplex.com/discussions/252531). I would maybe hold of on this until it gets sorted out

Comment: Since its a final year project use of external libaries should be avoided as much as possible as instructor will think i'm living on top of some external libraries. I used Google Static Map API and it worked like magic Thanks a lot guys for the time.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution would be to just use the `WebBrowser` control, then you don't have to embed anything.

Comment: This is a great point actually... You can pass a well formed URL including the latitude/longitude.  Not sure about the marker though.

Comment: oww sweet :) this did work actually. But still I prefer inside the native app than launching the browser.

Comment: Markers are Javascript based so that can be modified in the HTML or can be injected http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153748/how-to-inject-javascript-in-webbrowser-control

Comment: Thanks :) I used static API :)