# web browser set javascript variable value

Tags: c#, javascript

Is there a way for me to get and set the values of JavaScript variables in a win form web browser so it can communicate with my application.
The only way I can think of accomplishing this is by using a proxy of an invisible element such as a div that will have an attribute or inner HTML set to the value I want to read/write.

Also, is there a JavaScript function that gets me the cursor's current position.
Not event based callsbacks that have the position in its parameters. This is for a complicated application.

Comment: you should ask two questions in two questions.

Comment: I believe the answer to your second question is "No". As far as I know you have to use `onmousemove` and store the coordinates yourself, possibly in conjunction with `onmouseout` to allow for when the user moves the mouse entirely out of the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the simplest way is to inject script element into the document containing necessary java-script. See this SO question for how to do that: [How to inject Javascript in WebBrowser control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153748/how-to-inject-javascript-in-webbrowser-control)

Another (recommended) way is to use [WebBrowser.ObjectForScripting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.objectforscripting.aspx) that can be used to communicate between your application and java-script within web browser. You also need to use [browserControl.Document.InvokeScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.invokescript.aspx) method to trigger the java-script functions. InvokeScript can also be used instead of script injection method.

For second question, AFAIK, cursor position has to be tracked using mouse events.