# How to inject Javascript in WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control, inject

There is a great tutorial here about windows forms

[How to inject Javascript in WebBrowser control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153748/how-to-inject-javascript-in-webbrowser-control)

I tried it and it works great

But the problem is the objects used there is not recognized at wpf application. So what i am asking is what is the equivalent of the function below in wpf application. Thank you.

```
HtmlElement head = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
HtmlElement scriptEl = webBrowser1.Document.CreateElement("script");
IHTMLScriptElement element = (IHTMLScriptElement)scriptEl.DomElement;
string srJquery = File.ReadAllText("jquery.txt");
element.text = srJquery;
head.AppendChild(scriptEl);
```

the function above is working perfectly at windows form application c# 4.0 but the used objects such as HtmlElement is not recognized at WPF application.

Comment: HtmlElement lives in SYstem.Windows.Browser and System.Windows.Forms

Comment: I am pretty this function can also be written for WPF application

Comment: This code uses the nice wrapper classes available in Winforms for HtmlElement and HtmlDocument.  WPF doesn't have them.  Using the Winforms browser is an obvious workaround.

Comment: Hans Passant so you mean this can't be done in more advanced application WPF ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does this work?

```
    private void WebBrowser_LoadCompleted
       (object sender,
        System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        var webBrowser = sender as WebBrowser;

        var document
           = webBrowser.Document as mshtml.HTMLDocument;
        var ahref
           = document.getElementsByTagName("A").Cast<mshtml.IHTMLElement>().First();
        ahref.setAttribute(
           "onmouseenter",
           "javascript:alert('Hi');", 1);
    }
```

You need is `Microsoft.mshtml` (the .net API and not MS office one) reference.

Also please see this code for WPF webbrowser control that uses `ObjectForScripting` property of `WebBrowser` which can help you in injecting javascript...

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpf/archive/2011/05/27/how-does-wpf-webbrowser-control-handle-window-external-notify.aspx

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: i need to inject javascript not set attribute of element.

Comment: Did u explore `WebBrowser.ObjectForScripting`'s scope as I indicated.

Answer (score 3):

The best answer I found on the net was from http://clistax.com/question/qt/153748/st/4eb64b29180c4

I believe the most simple method to inject Javascript in a WebBrowser Control HTML Document from c# is to invoke the "execStrip" method with the code to be injected as argument.

In this example the javascript code is injected and executed at global scope:

```
var jsCode="alert('hello world from injected code');";
WebBrowser.Document.InvokeScript("execScript", new Object[] { jsCode, "JavaScript" });
```

If you want to delay execution, inject functions and call them after:

```
var jsCode="function greet(msg){alert(msg);};";
WebBrowser.Document.InvokeScript("execScript", new Object[] { jsCode, "JavaScript" });

WebBrowser.Document.InvokeScript("greet",new object[] {"hello world"});
```

This is valid for Windows Forms and WPF WebBrowser controls.

This solution is not cross browser because "execScript" is defined only in IE and Chrome. But the question is about Microsoft WebBrowser controls and IE is the only one supported.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic makes this easy. You just have to remember we're working with a `Microsoft.mshtml`.

```
private void wb_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{

    if (wb != null && wb.Document != null)
    {
        dynamic document = wb.Document;
        dynamic script = document.createElement("script");
        script.type = @"text/javascript";
        script.text = @"alert('hello world');";
        try { document.head.appendChild(script); } catch (Exception ex) { } // Dynamic property head does not exist.
    }
}
```

**Hint:** Make sure your using `Navigated` and not `Navigating` to ensure the document is populated.

I find myself setting `script.text` using `System.IO.File.ReadAllText(pathToJs)` to load local javascript files quite often. Since the embedded we browser can often be outdated, it's become pretty standard for me to inject things like [polyfill](https://polyfill.io/v3/) into my Windows Forms and WPF `WebBrowser` applications.

Answer (score 0):

I found this that help that talks about invokescript eqivilent in wpf for just executing script code inside html:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc452443.aspx