# How to inject a Javascript script into webpage using WebBrowser control?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, webbrowser-control

In my application I need to use a WebBrowser control to process user login. I use WPF and it's WebBrowser control. The problem is that I want to display a part of web page that is under certain div. I found a solution to this, I need to inject an javascript script into a loaded html page, but I have no clue how to do it :(

This is the script that I would like to inject into web.

```
function showHide() { 
     $('body >').hide(); 
     $('#div').show().prependTo('body'); 
}
```

So i could later call it `webbrowser1.InvokeScript("showHide");`

I read a lot of posts on stack, but all of them refer to WindowsForms WebBrowser and it is not working with WPF one.

EDIT: I tried:

```
private void PageLoaded (object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    var webBrowser = sender as WebBrowser;

    webBrowser.Document.InvokeScript("execScript",
            new object[] {"$('body >').hide(); $('#" + _div + "').show().prependTo('body');"});

}
```

But `webBrowser.Document` is type object and I cannot call InvokeScript on it, have no clue to what I should cast it.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to inject Javascript in WebBrowser control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7998996/how-to-inject-javascript-in-webbrowser-control)

Comment: It is not working with WPF control so it is not duplicate...

Comment: I get to the point `var script = var script = (mshtml.IHTMLScriptElement)doc.createElement("script");doc.createElement("script");` and I didn't know to what I should cast it. But before I finished editing you posted your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a reference to `mshtml`

[image]

In whatever event you want to inject the JavaScript:

```
var doc = (mshtml.HTMLDocument)webBrowser1.Document;
var head = doc.getElementsByTagName("head").Cast<mshtml.HTMLHeadElement>().First();
var script = (mshtml.IHTMLScriptElement)doc.createElement("script");
script.text = "function myFunction() { alert(\"Hello!\");}";
head.appendChild((mshtml.IHTMLDOMNode)script);
```

In whatever event you want to invoke the JavaScript from:

```
webBrowser1.InvokeScript("myFunction");
```

Result:

[image]