# Disable Javascript alert on wpf c#

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, wpf

I want to disable javascript alert on wpf(Windows Presentation Foundation.)

Javascript alert on wpf
[Wpf Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76pd8.png)

But, I don't want to disable javascript alert on WebBrowser

Javascript allert on WebBrowser
[Webbrowser Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inuIN.png)

**WPF**

```
private void ClickOKButton()
{
    IntPtr hwnd = FindWindow("#32770", "Web sayfasından ileti");
    hwnd = FindWindowEx(hwnd, IntPtr.Zero, "Button", "OK");
    uint message = 0xf5;
    SendMessage(hwnd, message, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
}

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    wbBrowser.Navigate(new Uri("http://localhost/AlertWebProject"));
    wbBrowser.LoadCompleted += WbBrowserOnLoadCompleted;
    wbBrowser.Navigated += WbBrowser_Navigated;
}

private void WbBrowser_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    ClickOKButton();
}

private void WbBrowserOnLoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs navigationEventArgs)
{
    ClickOKButton();
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
      <script>  
          function test() {
              alert("Test");
          }               
      </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
  <button onclick="test();">Test</button>
    <p>dsadsadas</p>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So you want to suppress alerts when they are in the WPF `WebBrowser` control, but not when they are in a regular web browser window (like Chrome)? Your best bet might be to inject some javascript in your WPF application to redefine `alert`

Comment: @MattBurland That sounds like a good idea. I'd upvote it if you made it an answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet might be to inject some javascript into the `WebBrowser` control to redefine `alert`. You can look at, for example, this question for how to inject javascript:

[How to inject Javascript in WebBrowser control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7998996/how-to-inject-javascript-in-webbrowser-control)

Then all you need to do is inject a snippet like:

```
window.alert = function() {}
```

And now any call to `alert` will do nothing.