# How to load HTML/JavaScript from embedded resource into winform web browser

Tags: c#, javascript, html, webbrowser-control

I want to have some HTML files with JavaScript loaded into the web browser control in a winforms (v2.0) application. During execution, I won't have internet access, so JavaScript and HTML forms will be embedded in he resources.resx file.

1) how can I load an HTML document out of the resource (analogous to a file:/// operation, but it isn't being loaded from the file system),

2) how would I declare the JavaScript scripts to be loaded?  I.e.,

```
<script src=resource.jquery.min.js??? ... />
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

To load the HTML document, just compile your html file as embedded resource, and then:

```
WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();
browser.DocumentText = Properties.Resources.<your_html_file>;
```

If you really need to have external .js files, I think you will probably need to make them embedded resources. Then you can read these resources into a string of javascript.

```
string GetResourceString(string scriptFile) 
{ 
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(); 
    Stream str = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(scriptFile); 
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(str, Encoding.ASCII);
    return sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

(Adapted from [a reply on this page](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/csharp/2/24426/javascript--c.aspx))

From here, look into IHTMLScriptElement. From what I understand, you may be able to use this javascript string and set it as the ITHMLScriptElement's text field. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153748/how-to-inject-javascript-in-webbrowser-control)

Good luck.

Comment: This won't work as is. When built as an Embedded Resource, `Properties.Resources.<your_html_file>` will return the contents as a byte array.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the file structure.

[image]

I had success by doing this:

Set the properties of the html files in my solution like this:

```
Build Action -> Content
Copy to Output Directory -> Copy always
```

Configure my webBrowser object properties like this:

```
var myAssembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;
var path = myAssembly.Substring(0, myAssembly.Length - "MyLib.DLL".Length) + "WebViews/prototype/index.html";
webBrowser.Url = new Uri(path);
```

Comment: You should use the `System.IO.Path` functions like `GetDirectoryName` here instead of manually slicing with `Substring`.  Also note this will result in `file:///` URLs which won't be friendly to ajax-type requests.