# jmeter report details issue: showing incorrect count

Tags: jmeter

Getting incorrect details in jmeter index.html file.
I have passed 450 users for performance test and in logs i can see the correct count which 450. But when i see the same in index.html file it is showing something like below.

```
**label   count**
APIName    450
APIName-0  226
APIName-1  226
```

and total count it is showing as "902" which is incorrect. It should be 450
[![jmeter snippet][1]][1]

"https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOao2.png"
and my https sampler name is "APIName"

Comment: Can you run the test with a single user and analyze the test results to get a better understanding of the outcome?  You can use the view result tree listener to analyze the details.

Comment: Hi @JaneshKodikara , I tried that it only happens when test starts failing when I pass more that 400 users. For One users it executes perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what is the cause of these extra results without seeing at least first 3 lines of your [.jtl file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles)

The most common causes are:

1. [Redirect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections) (i.e. from HTTP to HTTPS or whatever)
2. [Embedded resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33996804/web-browser-and-embedded-resources) (images, scripts, styles. fonts, etc.) however I don't think it's applicable to API

The options are in:

1. Define the filter for the HTML Reporting Dashboard so it would report only `APIName`

   ```
   jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.series_filter=^(APIName)(-success|-failure)?$
   ```
2. Tell JMeter to not to store the metrics on sub-samples:

   ```
   jmeter.save.saveservice.subresults=false
   ```

Both properties overrides should to to *user.properties* file, it lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation.

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Filtering Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#saveservice_requirements)
- [Results file configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: Thanks @Dimitri, Second option resolved my issue.