# How to remove wordwrap from a webbrowser and or set font size smaller

Tags: c#

I am using a 2 web browsers to compare texts, and when the lines become to long it wraps my text, i would like to remove this or lower my font size to avoid this.

Can some one please advise me on how to remove the word warp or change font size on `web Browsers`?

**The word wrap below totally miss alines my compare:**

[image]

Comment: Assuming you'd like to link both "lists" anyway, have you thought about using a `ListView` with custom element drawing? That way you could use one row per line/block and draw them the way you'd like, without having a scroll bar inbetween.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not adjust font size or wrapper text from the web control its self. So you should adjust the styling of the elements inside the web browser.

I adjusted the styling at the same place i styled the green and red highlighting.

```
    html.Append("<ins style=\"white-space:nowrap; display:inline; background:#e6ffe6;\">")
        .Append(text)
        .Append("</ins>");
```

> "white-space:nowrap; display:inline;

The above code is what i added to remove word wrapping.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no property of the web browser control that can do this. The presentation of the web page is controlled entirely by the web page itself.

If you cannot change the web page itself, the best you can do is to possibly cache a local version and change its styling using `WebBrowser.Document.ExecCommand()`. `WebBrowser.Document.InvokeScript()` also works but requires already-defined JS, so we have to go ahead and add in the script manually.

```
HtmlElement head = webBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
HtmlElement script = webBrowser.Document.CreateElement("script");
IHTMLScriptElement element = (IHTMLScriptElement)script.DomElement;
element.text = "function adjust { document.getElementById('yourIdHere').style.whiteSpace='nowrap'; }";
head.AppendChild(script);
webBrowser.Document.InvokeScript("adjust");
```

Just find the div id of the text by looking at the web page's source code and you should be golden. If it doesn't have a div id, you can use other JS methods (such as getElementsByTagName) to find it.

Comment: No problem. I just had to re-edit my post because I accidentally put the wrong method name in.

Comment: So some thing like WebBrowser.Document.ExecCommand(white-space: nowrap) ?? How would i invokeScript or ExecCommand?

Comment: This question has a good working example of using InvokeScript: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153748/how-to-inject-javascript-in-webbrowser-control. I'll edit my answer to put some code in.

Comment: I would prefer not having a JS file and just ExecCommand a little line of text if that is possible ? but will check out that link now :)

Comment: I edited my answer again. Check it out to see if it works for you. I'm sure there is also a way to do this with ExecCommand but I'm not too well-versed with it.

Comment: @Pommy It uses System.Windows.Forms. But I think it may be deprecated. I haven't used it in a long time and the documentation for it isn't the greatest.

Comment: How would i do this?? i'm trying webbrowser.Document.ExecCommand("white-space:nowrap;", false, false); What do each of these parameters mean?

Comment: @Pommy That's isn't how Document.ExecCommand works. You can only use the commands here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533049(VS.85).aspx

Comment: I am Having problems with IHTMLScriptElement missing useing or assemblt referace.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by Pomster's Answer, that's what I did to get the best result:

```
String.Format("<div style='white-space:nowrap; display:inline;'>{0}</div>",text);
```

c# 6.0 version:

```
$"<div style='white-space:nowrap; display:inline;'>{text}</div>";
```