# How to disable message popups in a webbrowser in vb.net

Tags: javascript, vb.net

I want to disable that when you close a website it shows a message like ("Stay there and....do you really want to leave?"). How can I do it? The website is in a webbrowser, I cannot disable javascript because I need it.

Answer (score 1):

The code "do you really want to leave?" confirmation message is triggered on the `window.onbeforeunload` event. So you could add a javascript to the page which would overwrite that confirmation:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {};
```

To Register the javascript, use the `ClientScript.RegisterClientScript` method (can be added in your `Page_Load` :

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "BeforeUnloadScript", "window.onbeforeunload = function () {};", True);
```

Comment: Can you differ the client file from the code behind file? If so, `Page_Load` should already be in your code behind file.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly, this is a desktop application and you will need to inject javascript into the webbrowser control. you can either extend the existing webbrowser control, or, do something like this in document_complete:
[How to inject Javascript in WebBrowser control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153748/how-to-inject-javascript-in-webbrowser-control)

you need inject window.onbeforeunload if it is the function called by the popup (depends on the site you browse).