# how to hide div using javascript for web browser in wp7

Tags: c#, javascript, windows-phone-7, browser

I Am developing simple wp7 app for learning.
I want to do the below tasks In Windows Phone 7 application.

navigate to a webpage (http://some-url/) and am able to load this page(using webBrowser) i don't want to display header div (on top of the page). how can i call java script (InvokeScript) for this web browser page

and this html webpage is not my app.

Comment: do you have any access to this web page ??

Comment: yes am developing app for those:)

Comment: Try to [InvokeScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc491132%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) and create a javascript function to hide this div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the above @Aure77 ans works fine but apply Invoke script function diff

you can use `InvokeScript` function to remove or hide am also struggled to solve this I think Your are using `InvokeScript` in `PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded`, `webBrowser1_Navigated` that will throws errors

and you can use this method in another event handler like `MainPage_MouseLeftButtonDown`, `webBrowser1_LoadCompleted` and the code is

```
private void webBrowser1_LoadCompleted(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.InvokeScript("eval", "document.getElementsByTagName('your_div_name')[0].style.display = 'none';");
    }
```

that works fine for me :) try this

Comment: thanks kartheek this is perfrct and thanks a lot u save my time

Comment: The solution was in my comment ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
    function HideDiv(id) {
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
    }
    function ShowDiv(id) {
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
    }
    </script>
 </head>
<body>
    <div id="hide-me">Hide me !</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Using you're WebView :

*Hide div :*

```
wv.InvokeScript("HideDiv", new string[] { "hide-me" });
```

*Show div :*

```
wv.InvokeScript("ShowDiv", new string[] { "hide-me" });
```

Comment: this `invokeScript` is used to hide the html page that u written above but i am calling url and want to hide those page any way ?

Comment: So, look this method : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153748/how-to-inject-javascript-in-webbrowser-control or try with eval function (`wv.InvokeScript("eval", new String[] { "my js code" }`);

Answer (score 1):

You can try using jQuery. For example, if the header id is #header then:

```
$("#header").hide();
```

Comment: how can i include this in my wp7 app. i know jquery and java script :)

Comment: wp? Do you mean Wordpress?

Comment: If not then you try to load the data as xml and only show the elements which you need.

try jquery:
 var jqxhr = $.get(xmlFilePath, function(data) {
  xmlData = data;
 })

Answer (score 0):

using InvokeScript :

code to call javascript function from wp app

```
webBrowser1.InvokeScript("hideDiv","");
```

javascript code

```
 function hideDiv(){
    document.getElementById('Your_Div_ID').style.display='none';
    }
```

Comment: that html page in not in my app. and where can i include this js in my app