# Clicking a html button

Tags: c#, html, button, click, invoke

This is the button I'm trying to click:

```
<td class="dark" onclick="document.getElementById('id').value = '0'; document.getElementById('form').submit()">
   test
</td>
```

I tried this code that uses the Winform WebBrowser control to click on that element:

```
HtmlElementCollection links = webBrowser1.Document.Links;

foreach (HtmlElement link in links)
{
    if ((link.InnerText != null) && (link.InnerText.Equals("test")))
        link.InvokeMember("Click");
}
```

It clicks links but not on buttons like the one I posted above. I tried different things like this as well:

```
if (curElement.GetAttribute("id").Equals("0"))
{
    curElement.InvokeMember("click");
}
```

What is the correct way to click that table cell from the WebBrowser control?

Comment: Try using this SO answer to invoke a script.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153748/how-to-inject-javascript-in-webbrowser-control

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that what you call a 'link' isn't a link in terms of the WebBrowser but a so called tablecell which is in html expressed as a `<td>` tag which is explained [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td). That is the reason when you iterate over the `document.links` collection you don't find what you're looking for.

You can use another method on the Document property of the [webbrowsercontrol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) to get a list of specifc tag names, [GetEelementsByTagName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.getelementsbytagname.aspx). That will give you just `<td>`'s. With a simple if you can check if you arrived at the correct `<td>` and then call [RaiseEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.raiseevent.aspx) on the element to invoke the desired behavior.

```
  foreach (HtmlElement td in this.webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("td")) 
  {
         Debug.WriteLine(td.InnerText);
        if (td.InnerText.Equals("test"))
        {
                     td.RaiseEvent("onclick");
        }
  }
```