# Way to remove localstorage created by JavaScript in C#

Tags: c#, javascript, cordova, windows-phone-7.1, local-storage

I am developing Windows phone 7.1 PhoneGap app. I would like to remove localstorage which was created by `window.localStorage.setItem` JavaScript code in C#. I know, in JavaScript we can remove using  `window.localStorage.removeItem`. But, I want to remove from code behind C#. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you using a WebBrowser control? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153748/how-to-inject-javascript-in-webbrowser-control

Comment: I tried WebBrowser, But some unknown error occurs with exception.

Answer (score 6):

Use this code,

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "YourUniqueScriptKey", 
        "localStorage.removeItem(key);", true);
```

***note:** local storage is a client side and C# is serverside. so simple you cannot access client side items with c#. but in above code it will run a javascript code in the first page load after your c# event.*

Comment: I am developing Windows phone app. In that ScriptManager is not supported.

Comment: that is also not supported in Windows phone 7.1 app. I came across both of them already and tried them.

Comment: final but ugly option is using `Response.Write("<script>localStorage.removeItem(key);</script>");`

Comment: if this one also not working, better to ask new question and tag windows phone app then people have knowledge about it will reply