# How to embed javascript chat client into C#

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, winforms, livechat

I am using .NET 4.0 and C# to develop a standard forms application.  I have a help menu that I wanted to provide a "Chat" option.  We are currently using LiveChat for our "chat client".  They provide similar Javascript that you would use in a web browser to use as your chat client.  If I have a user click on the "Chat" Menu Item, how could I launch a browser and use this java script to open up a chat session?

```
(function() {
    delete(window.LC_API);
    delete(window.LC_Invite);
    delete(window.__lc_iframe_current_skill);
    delete(window.__lc_inited);
    delete(window.__lc_lang);
    var lc = document.createElement('script'); lc.type = 'text/javascript'; lc.async = true;
    lc.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'cdn.livechatinc.com/tracking.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(lc, s);
})();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can open a window with the [WebBrowser Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

and navigate to the a local html file with the javascript chat code in it. Or you could navigate to a remote url with the code in it.

On windows the web browser control uses IE under the hood. I do not know how this would work on other systems.

If you need other types of browser support there is also [Awesomium](http://www.awesomium.com/) which is more like Chrome's rendering engine, and [GeckoFx](https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/) which is more Firefox's engine.

Comment: There is a [good example](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/How-to-inject-javascript-f3970459) from Microsoft of using JavaScript code in WebBrowser in Windows Forms application. Also there is a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153748/how-to-inject-javascript-in-webbrowser-control) by injecting JavaScript in WebBrowser control on StackOverflow.