# C# write a string to a variable defined in %name% in a loaded html page in WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, html, winforms

I loaded a html local file in a WebBrowser control within a WinForm. In the html code, I defined some variables in %variables%.

My question is how to transfer/reference strings/data from WinForm to the %viarables% defined in the loaded html page, and refresh the loaded html page displayed on the WebBrowser.

Following is the code of loading a local html file from. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

By the way, it is a WinForm application, not asp.Net.

> ```
>         string curDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
>         this.webBrowser1.Url = new Uri(String.Format("file:///{0}/{1}", curDir + "\\Forms", fileName));
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to replace your variables after loading the HTML, which could be problematic, why not read the source file, replace the variables, then load the updated document into the web browser control?  This seems much more straightforward.

For example:

```
string dir = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "forms");
string html = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(dir, fileName));
foreach (string variable in GetListOfVariables())
{
    html = html.Replace(variable, GetReplacementForVariable(variable));
}
webBrowser1.DocumentText = html;
```

Comment: No problem; glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have control over contents of the HTML file? You could try [InvokeScript](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc452443(v=vs.110).aspx) method paired with a Javascript function prepared in the document beforehand.

If you don't control the contents, then you can inject javascript from your code. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153748/how-to-inject-javascript-in-webbrowser-control) are some examples of doing that.

Comment: Dmitriy, thanks for your suggestion. I didn't write a control over the contents.