# WebBrowser Control prevent Next Url navigated

Tags: javascript, vb.net, webbrowser-control, onbeforeunload

I wonder if there is a anyway to remove the WebBrowser Message

> are you sure you want to navigate away from this page

When I try to navigate another url, it happens.

[image: Erro picture]

I tried this methods

```
e.Cancel = False

WebBrowser1.Dispose()

WebBrowser1 = New WebBrowser

WebBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True

WebBrowser1.Navigate(New Uri("https://www.google.com"))
```

Comment: is there any unclear info please tell me i will change them immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is coded into the website, so you'd have to inject some Javascript into the page to override the prompt.

Be careful with this, though. This requires overriding the entire [`window.onbeforeunload` event handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload), and some pages might have decided to do more than just display a prompt (perhaps save data or something similar).

To start with add a reference to `mshtml`, this is required to be able to set the contents of a script element (credit to [Atanas Korchev](https://stackoverflow.com/a/154496)):

1. Right-click your project in the `Solution Explorer` and press `Add Reference...`.
2. Select the `Browse` tab and navigate to `C:\Windows\System32`
3. Select `mshtml.tlb` and press OK.
4. In the `Solution Explorer`, expand the `References` node. If you can't expand it or if it doesn't exist, press the `Show All Files` button in the top of the `Solution Explorer`.
5. Select the `mshtml` reference, go to the `Property Window` and make sure `Embed Interop Types` is set to `True`.

Now you can use this code:

```
Private Sub RemoveOnBeforeUnloadPrompt()
    If WebBrowser1.Document IsNot Nothing AndAlso WebBrowser1.Document.Body IsNot Nothing Then
        'Create a <script> tag.
        Dim ScriptElement As HtmlElement = WebBrowser1.Document.CreateElement("script")
        ScriptElement.SetAttribute("type", "text/javascript")

        'Insert code to override the window.onbeforeunload event handler.
        CType(ScriptElement.DomElement, mshtml.IHTMLScriptElement).text = "function __removeOnBeforeUnload() { window.onbeforeunload = function() {}; }"

        'Append script to the web page.
        WebBrowser1.Document.Body.AppendChild(ScriptElement)

        'Run the script.
        WebBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("__removeOnBeforeUnload")
    End If
End Sub
```

Then, *before* you navigate to a new page call:

```
RemoveOnBeforeUnloadPrompt()
```

Comment: it say "InvokeScript"Not Member of WebBrowser1

Comment: @Beginner01 : Yeah, I believe you. No need for an image ;). I updated my answer, sorry about that.

Comment: i think the problem with the main page of website before navigate to a new page ?!

Comment: i can send the main page that may help you to figure it out. why it not navigate the next page

Comment: @Beginner01 : Hmm, okay. Seems there was more to it than just setting `InnerText`. I'll update my answer in a bit.

Comment: @Beginner01 : I don't know what that has got to do with anything, but anyway I updated my answer.

Comment: unfortunately it has some error too.
okey i will do my best to know how to solve it, big thanks for your helping.

Comment: @Beginner01 : I don't understand, you're gonna do your best trying to know how to solve what?

Comment: i will try to negative another link, cause your currently method not work with me unfortunately.

Comment: @Beginner01 : Not even after my update? That's strange... I'll have to test this later when I get the chance (I'm currently on my phone).

Comment: thanks it not a word for you, cause it little to say, you are awesome , also i will try hard to figure it out with you

Comment: No more Talk, you definitely number 1 , Big thanks, it worked perfectly without any error. and it successfully navigate the next page.

Comment: @Beginner01 : Always glad I can help! Though I'm very confused right now... So you didn't see my update before, or...? :)

Comment: i Saw your new update since15 min ago, and i already made it from your update.

Comment: that's why i mark your answered as that correct answer, Because you are the best, and your method it work , i import mshtml.tlb , and edit code as you said , now all work good.

Comment: @Beginner01 : Okay, glad to hear it worked! Good luck with your future endeavours! -- **EDIT:** I just noticed that my phone had done an autocorrect: `Embed Interpol Types` should've been `Embed Interop Types`. I corrected this in my answer as well.

Comment: yeh i notice that when you said that you use your android., also im big fan of you, you are almost my Engine search on stackoverflow thread you answered almost my search question's.

Comment: @Beginner01 : I have an iPhone! _\*ghasp\*_ - Hehe, as I said, I'm glad I can help!