# I wish to replace text in a web page in C#

Tags: c#, text, replace, mshtml

Here is the code that I am using

```
 private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
     IHTMLDocument2 doc2 = webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument as IHTMLDocument2;
     StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder(doc2.body.outerHTML);

     String substitution = "<span style='background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);'> sensor </span>";
     html.Replace("sensor", substitution);

     doc2.body.innerHTML = html.ToString();

       }
```

**It works**, but the I cannot use the **form** nor the **web browser**

I have tried to added

**webBrowser1.Document.Write(html.ToString()); //after doc2 at the end**

But the **webpage** displayed is not **formmatted correctly**

**I would be grateful**, to get this **fixed**

Comment: I suspect that `webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted` occurs too late for this to work.

Comment: Thanks for responsing .. Can I fix this .. slow down the webBrowser_DocumentCompleted

Comment: That's not how events work.  I think you need to re-evaluate your approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to find your element in the `HTMLDocument` DOM and then manipulate the `innerHTML` property with the relevant HTML.

There are a variety of ways to do this, including injecting javascript ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153748/how-to-inject-javascript-in-webbrowser-control)) or using [HtmlAgilityPack](https://html-agility-pack.net).

The following code uses [GetElementsByTagName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.getelementsbytagname?view=netframework-4.8) DOM function to iterate over the `span` tags in the document on this site: https://www.w3schools.com/html/

It replaces all span text's including "Tutorial" with the html snippet your provided.

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var elements = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("span");
    foreach (HtmlElement element in elements)
    {
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(element.InnerText)) 
            continue;

        if (element.InnerText.Contains("Tutorial"))
        {
            element.InnerHtml = "<span style='background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);'> sensor </span>";
        }
    }
}
```