# C# probe for and capture Javascript Alert() and Confirm()

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer, automation, alert

So I've been doing some research for a while and I'm at a dead end. I'm doing some IE automation. In C#/.NET, how do I probe for and consume a javascript alert() or confirm() so I can do things like grab its text and click the OK\Cancel buttons?

**Update**:

I need to reiterate: I need to be able to pull and verify the text from an alert() or confirm() as well as send it an OK or Cancel click. An example of such a test would be to make sure that, when I click on delete, the confirm() doesn't say *"Are you sure you'd like to go to Mexico?"* or anything else except the proper message.

Just in case, let me reiterate: For the purposes of this test, I have **zero** control over the source of the website in question.

Lastly, I'm using `SHDocVw.InternetExplorer`.

Comment: Are you using IE or creating a custom application with a WebBrowser control?

Comment: By "probe for" are you handling the source pre-browser or only after it's displayed? Are you serving to yourself? Is it possible to have these things use modal dialogs instead of alert boxes and handle it in javascript?

Comment: Possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/77659/blocking-dialogs-in-net-webbrowser-control

Comment: @Zach I don't want to block the alerts

Comment: @codethis I am using ShDocVW.InternetExplorer for my automation. I'm touching the COM object.

Comment: @drachenstern I am not handling the source pre-browser. In fact, the site's source is completely out of my hands. My automation has to perform like an end user.

Comment: For an alert(), blocking and clicking OK should have identical behavior. For a confirm(), you can control the behavior using the same technique as the blocking, but return true or false depending on whether you want it to behave as though you clicked the OK or Cancel button.

Comment: If you use the `WebBrowser` it seems like a fairly easy task. With `ShDocVW.InternetExplorer` it's not clear that it's possible.

Comment: Have you tried using the WaTiN framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FindWindow - will get you close; you do want a window handle but you won't for sure know how to find it.

Better would be do use EnumWindows.Here's an example of a routine you can run every second or two that will give you a ton of info about every single window on the system, then you can analyze it. You can check the type of window, the text in it, get the buttons, and send a click message to the right one. It will let you do everything you are hoping to be able to do.

To get the text you send a wm_gettext and for the button you may get away with wm_click.

Sorry for the C. the next best example I could find was in LISP. Take time to read the code, you will see what the idea is. The Matching functions help determine if the text is right without knowing it exactly.

If you can manage to do this in c# I am betting you will get a lot shorter solution. (can you use LINQ on the output of EnumWindows?;-)

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include "resource.h"

#define ET_STARTUP 1
#define ET_WINDOWOPEN 2
#define ET_RUNEND 3
#define ET_USEREVENT 4
#define M_STAR 1
#define M_QUESTION 2

typedef struct WindowList_s
{
 int iScriptLine;
 HWND hwnd;
    char *stName;
 char *stTitle;
 char *stClassName;
 char *stParentName;
 struct WindowList_s *wlParentPtr;
 char *stChildName;
 struct WindowList_s *wlChildPtr;
 int bWarned;
 struct WindowList_s *next;
} WindowList_t;


////////////////



extern long g_runids[];
extern WindowList_t *g_windowlist;
extern EventList_t *g_eventlist;
char stWTx[2000];
char stWCl[200];
char stPTx[2500];
char stPCl[200];
int bEventEntry=0; // means we're inside of processing an event.
HWND LogWinParent;

void FixIt(char *buf,unsigned int siz)
{
 int i,j,bump;
 int ir;
 char cr;
 char hex[10];
 // keep special characters from screwing up script by
 // replacing w/ single-character wildcard
    for (i=0;buf[i];i++)
 {
  cr='\0';
  ir=0;
  bump=1;
  switch(buf[i])
  {
  case '\0':cr='0';break;
  case '\\':cr='\\';break;
  case '\n':cr='n';break;
  case '\t':cr='t';break;
  case '\a':cr='a';break;
  case '\b':cr='b';break;
  case '\f':cr='f';break;
  case '\r':cr='r';break;
  case M_STAR:cr='*';break;
  case M_QUESTION:cr='*';break;
  case '"':cr='"';break;
  default:
   if (buf[i]<32 || buf[i]>=127)
   {
    bump=2;
    ir=buf[i];
   }
   else
    bump=0;
  }
  if (bump)
  {
   for (j=strlen(buf)+bump+1>=siz-1?siz-1:strlen(buf)+1;
    j>i;j--)
     buf[j+bump]=buf[j];
   buf[siz-1]='\0';
   if (cr)
   {
    buf[i++]='\\';
    buf[i]=cr;
   }
   if (ir)
   {
    sprintf(hex,"\\x%00H",ir);
    memcpy(buf+i,hex,4);
    i+=4;
   }
  }
 }
}
void LogWin(HWND hw)
{
 static long ParentNum=0,ChildNum=0;

 GetWindowText(hw,stWTx,sizeof(stWTx)-1);
 GetClassName(hw,stWCl,sizeof(stWCl)-1);
 FixIt(stWTx,sizeof(stWTx));
 FixIt(stWCl,sizeof(stWCl));
 if (GetParent(hw)==LogWinParent)
 {
  ChildNum++;
  sprintf(stPTx,"        WindowObject %ld.%ld \"%s\" \"%s\" "
   "Parent %ld",ParentNum,ChildNum,stWTx,stWCl,ParentNum);
 }
 else if (hw==LogWinParent)
 {
  ChildNum=0;
  ParentNum++;
  sprintf(stPTx,"    WindowObject %ld \"%s\" \"%s\"",
   ParentNum,stWTx,stWCl);
 }
 else 
 {
  ChildNum++;
  sprintf(stPTx,"            WindowObject %ld.%ld \"%s\" \"%s\" GRANDCHILD",
   ParentNum,ChildNum,stWTx,stWCl);
 }
 log_it(stPTx);
}

BOOL CALLBACK EnumChildProc4Logging(  HWND hwnd,LPARAM lParam )
{
    LogWin(hwnd);
 return 1;
}

void LogCurrentWindows(void)
{
 static int bEntry=0;
 static HWND hwCurrentFocus = 0;

 if (bEntry)
  return;
 bEntry=1;
    LogWinParent=GetForegroundWindow();
 if (LogWinParent!=hwCurrentFocus)
 {
  hwCurrentFocus=LogWinParent;
  LogWin(LogWinParent);
  EnumChildWindows(LogWinParent,EnumChildProc4Logging,0); 
 }
 bEntry=0;
}


/******************************************************************/
/* match() - parse wildcard strings .                             */
/******************************************************************/
int match(char *pattern,char *str)
{
    int patt,st;

    patt=0;
    st=0;
    while(pattern[patt] || str[st])  /* go until both at '\0' */
    {
        if ((!pattern[patt] || !str[st]) && pattern[patt]!=M_STAR)
            return 0;  /* fail if one at '\0' */
        if (pattern[patt]==M_STAR)
        {
            patt++;
            while (str[st] && !match(pattern+patt,str+st))
            st++;
        }
        else if (pattern[patt]!=M_QUESTION && pattern[patt]!=str[st])
            return 0;  /* Oh, No!! no match. */
        else
        {
            patt++;
            st++;
        }
    }
    return 1;  /* successful match */
}
void CheckWindowList(HWND hwnd)
{
 WindowList_t *wl;
 HWND hwndParent,hwndTarget;
 static char buf[600];
 // Get the window's class and text
 GetWindowText(hwnd,stWTx,sizeof(stWTx)-1);
 GetClassName(hwnd,stWCl,sizeof(stWCl)-1);
 // Get the Parent Window's class and text
 hwndParent=GetParent(hwnd);
 GetWindowText(hwndParent,stPTx,sizeof(stPTx)-1);
 GetClassName(hwndParent,stPCl,sizeof(stPCl)-1);

 // search thru window objects, fill in 
 // matching hwnds as appropriate
 for (wl=g_windowlist;wl;wl=wl->next)
 {
  hwndTarget=NULL; // separate variable enables 
                // warning on duplicate matches
  if (wl->wlChildPtr==NULL && wl->wlParentPtr==NULL)
  { // no parent/child requirements
   if (match(wl->stClassName,stWCl) && 
     match(wl->stTitle,stWTx) )
       hwndTarget=hwnd;
  }
  else if (wl->wlParentPtr)
  { // parent requirement - if I (hwnd) match the 
    // wl's class/title and the parent (hwndParent)
          // matches the wl's parentptr's class/title then
    // set 'me' as the window that matches and has
    // the proper parent requirement.
   if (match(wl->stClassName,stWCl) && 
     match(wl->stTitle,stWTx) &&
     match(wl->wlParentPtr->stClassName,stPCl) && 
     match(wl->wlParentPtr->stTitle,stPTx) )
       hwndTarget=hwnd;
  }
  else
  { // child requirement - if I (hwnd) match the child
    // requirement's stuff and the parent(hwndParent)
    // matches the wl's stuff then set the parent
    // as that wl's hwnd.
   if (match(wl->stClassName,stPCl) && 
     match(wl->stTitle,stPTx) &&
     match(wl->wlChildPtr->stClassName,stWCl) && 
     match(wl->wlChildPtr->stTitle,stWTx) )
       hwndTarget=hwndParent;
  }
  if (hwndTarget)
  {
   if (wl->hwnd && !wl->bWarned ) // log a warning on dup windows
   {
    sprintf(buf,"267.EnumChildProc4Search.10 "
     "Warning: more than one match for "
     "windowobject %s exists",wl->stName);
    log_it(buf);
    wl->bWarned =1;
   }
   else
    wl->hwnd=hwndTarget;
  }
 }
}
BOOL CALLBACK EnumChildProc4Search(  HWND hwnd,LPARAM lParam )
{
    CheckWindowList(hwnd);
    // return value of 1 means continue with rest of enumeration.
 return 1;
}

// to enumerate all... enumchild w/ NULL hwnd don't work???!
BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowProc4Search(  HWND hwnd,LPARAM lParam )
{
    CheckWindowList(hwnd);
 EnumChildWindows(hwnd,EnumChildProc4Search,0);
 return 1;
}

// Check thru all windows and runIDs to see if a run is done
// or a window has opened. First emumerate the windows and running 
// programs and then see which events should be run.
// this function must not run if blocked, 'once' countdown
// has run out, or stopscript=1, or entry = 1
void RunEvents(void)
{
// Please keep in mind this program's error philosphoy when
// extending it, namely, catch all possible script errors
// when loading script, but do not display messageboxes for
// even the most serious errors when doing events, because 
// the idea is to catch errors during development and avoid
// errors at run time or in production!!
 static bEventEntry=0;
 WindowList_t *wl;
 EventList_t *el;
 ParmList_t *pl;
 char *st;
 int i;
 long lExitCode;

 // exit this routine if we shouldn't be here
    if (g_iStopScript || bEventEntry)
  return;
 bEventEntry=1;
 // clear all of the window handles in windowobject list
 for (wl=g_windowlist;wl;wl=wl->next)
 {
  wl->hwnd=NULL;
  wl->bWarned = 0;
 }

 // enumerate all windows in the system; repopulate all of
 // the window handles in the windowobject list
 EnumWindows(EnumWindowProc4Search,0);

 // go thru event list, calling any events that must 
 // be called; windows handles for any subsequent actions
 // will have been set by above code. Check for runs ending
 // to process runend events and search the windowobject list
 // to process windowopen events. 
 for (el=g_eventlist;g_eventlist && el;el=el->next)
 {
  pl=MakeParms(el->stEventTypeSourceLine);
  st=ParmValue(pl,2); // event name
  // check for windowopen events
  if (el->iEventType==ET_WINDOWOPEN)
  { // search for their open windows!!
   for (wl=g_windowlist;wl;wl=wl->next)
   {
    if (0==_stricmp(wl->stName,st) && wl->hwnd)
     RunActions(el);
    if (g_iStopScript)
     return; // quit doing actions/events ASAP.  }
   }
  }
  if (el->iEventType==ET_RUNEND)
  {
   sscanf(st,"%ld",&i);
   if (g_runids[i]!=-1 && g_runids[i]!=0)
   {
    GetExitCodeProcess((HANDLE)g_runids[i],&lExitCode);
    if (lExitCode != STILL_ACTIVE) 
    {
     RunActions(el);
     g_runids[i]=0;
    }
   }
  }
  KillParms(pl);
 }
 bEventEntry=0;
}

void RunStartup(void)
{
 EventList_t *el;

    if (bEventEntry)
  return;
 bEventEntry=1;
 // check stopscript in case of endscript in startup event!
 for (el=g_eventlist;g_eventlist && el && !g_iStopScript;el=el->next)
 {
  if (el->iEventType==ET_STARTUP)
   RunActions(el);
 }
 bEventEntry=0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you're going to have to use FindWindow, SendMessage, etc.  This is how [WatiN](http://watin.sourceforge.net/) does its dialog handling.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is the [IDocHostshowUI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753269%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) COM interface.  If I read the documentation correctly and my assumptions are correct [ShowMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753271%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) function will be called when an alert() or confirm() is called in JavaScript.

I've not done this myself so I am only guessing.  Here are [some examples](http://www.faisoncomputing.com/samples/programming_samples.htm) of someone showing an example of using that interface (and many others) in C#.  WebBrowserSample2 sounds like what you are looking for.