# help can I stop wpf webbrowser popups?

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control

Does anyone know how to stop a popup from happening when using a webbrowser control within a WPF application ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Unfortunately there is no good way to
>   archive this right now. This is a good
>   feedback. We will add it to the list
>   of things to provide for the
>   WebBrowser control in the future
>   release.

Source:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/4d4fa88e-b8c8-4190-8153-db923ed0e24e/

Comment: What is there a hack i could use similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/77659/blocking-dialogs-in-net-webbrowser-control)

Comment: I don't know, have you tried that?  What happened when you did?

Answer (score 1):

You could simply select the WindowsFormsHost control, go inside the Constructor and set the ScriptErrorsSuppressed property to true for Blocking Pop ups .