# How to disable password manager for WebBrowser control

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

The problem is simple, I don't want my embedded browser to display any modal dialogs. User enters the password on the site, that's it. No dialog to "remember this password".

Please DO NOT answer with "use different browser". My question is exactly about `System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser` WPF control.

I KNOW that modifying the page HTML on the fly with `autocomplete="off"` works, but I wonder if there is a Windows Registry hack for that, as it's true for many other super annoying Internet Explorer quirks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Blocking dialogs in .NET WebBrowser control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77659/blocking-dialogs-in-net-webbrowser-control)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres a registry 'hack' for you:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings
```

Add a new DWORD Value to this directory.
The name needs to be `DisablePasswordCachingto` and it must be a hexadecimal type.
Insert `1` as value and you should be good to go.

Now you have successfully disabled the password caching in IE (and WPF browser).

> If this registry is set, then the standalone IE will not save any passwords too. It's a global option.

Links from where I got the solution:
[SO (which is not a good answer so I wrote this one)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47821832/7571526)
[Microsoft Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/229940/how-to-disable-internet-explorer-password-caching)